# SQL QUERY for available cars which are available

Tags: sql, laravel

I have two tables cars table and bookings table.I want to  list all the cars which are available between search dates from and to date, using la-ravel query builder.

```
$cars= DB::table('bookings')->select('*')
            ->where('from', '>=', $from)
           ->where('from', '<=', $till)
              ->where('status','!=','booked')
            ->get();
```

I am able to get results when from date is not between the dates of all ready booked cars. but I have a problem when from date and to date is not between the dates where car is already booked.

how can i check date ranges between the date ranges of the already booked cars from and to date.

Comment: I totally recommend you to use Eloquent, that is what is made for, so you don't use RAW DB anymore... If you are doing this, you did not understand anything of lavarel, so take a moment and re-read (I hope you done so...) the documentation because you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use models that`s  will be easier for you 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent has a `whereDate()` method that will help with this. Check the documentation for implementation details.